# Is it possible to access class methods from class instance in glib?

Tags: c, glib, gobject

I am receiving the following error when trying to call the "talk" function of my DogClass:
'talk' is not a member of _DogFile.

In fact, I have declared the dog file in the _DogFileClass struct,
and in the class_init I am pointing to the talk function.
How can I access the class method from the instance of the class?

I am including the relevant code:

dog.h:

```
struct _DogFileClass
{
    GObjectClass parent_class;
    void (*talk)(DogFile *self)
}

void dog_file_talk(DogFile *self);
```

dog.c

```
void dog_file_real_talk(DogFile *self);

void dog_file_class_init(DogFileClass *klass)
{
    klass->talk = dog_file_real_talk;
}

void dog_file_talk(DogFile *self)
{
    g_return_if_false(DOG_IS_FILE);
    DogFileClass *klass = DOG_FILE_GET_CLASS(self);
    return klass->talk(self);
}

dog_file_real_talk(DogFile *self)
{
    printf("WOOF")
}
```

and in the end I would like to use the talk function, in the following way:
`dog->talk(dog);`
when dog is a pointer to the DogFile class

Comment: Why are you using the `.cpp` suffix to write c code?! it will go through the C++ compiler

Comment: My fault, accidentally wrote cpp

Answer (score 1):

> and in the end I would like to use the talk function, in the following way: dog->talk(dog); when dog is a pointer to the DogFile class

That’s not possible, because `talk` is not a member of the `DogFile` struct. Your code in `dog_file_talk()` looks correct, so instead of trying to use `dog->talk (dog)`, use `dog_file_talk (dog)`.

I’m afraid that’s the closest you can get to OOP in C with GObject. If you were to have a `talk` member on the `DogFile` struct, that pointer would be duplicated for each instance of `DogFile`, which would prevent it being overrideable by subclasses, as well as being a waste of memory.

If you want more ‘natural’ OOP, use C++ (or a more modern language such as Rust) directly.